# Permission denied on git clone of my own private repo on a remote server - even though I added a new public key and all

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have been setting up an instance of a server (Amazon EC2, Ubuntu 12.x), and have got stuck trying to clone my own private repo from git.

I've been looking at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys and https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey for a while, but still no good.

I have generated a new ssh key pair on the remote machine with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemailaddress@myemail.com"
```

and set up my git config fine, **and I have added the public key to my github account**. The email address is the same as the one I use on my local machine's ssh key (I don't know if that matters).

After starting an ssh-agent and then doing `ssh-add -l`, I get a fingerprint result that matches what is said in my github public key. `ssh -T git@github.com` also tells me that I have successfully authenticated.

However, whenever I try

```
git clone https://github.com/dmonopoly/myprivateproject.git
```

or

```
git clone git@github.com:dmonopoly/myprivateproject.git
```

on the remote machine (which I have sshed into),
I get this error:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'myprivateproject'.: Permission denied
```

Ideas? I've handled the `permission denied (public key)` before, but this seems different. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'myprivateproject'.: Permission denied
>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

That has nothing at all to do with access to the repository. You are trying to clone it to a directory where you don't have write access. Check permissions **on the machine running `git clone`**.

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much - I feel ridiculous not realizing it was such a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

sudo in front of the command took care of it for me.  Easier than tracing the folder needing a permission change.